# SplitViewController primaryViewController has no way of being dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-universal-app

I have a `UISplitViewController` with default behaviour. When `showViewController(..)` executes, it presents a new `UINavigationController` that I have passed. Sometimes this `UINavigationController` is presented modally (based on `TraitCollection`).

I have noticed that a `UINavigationController` (or any VC for that matter) is only presented modally when using a horizontally/vertically compact size class. What is missing however is a method of going back or simply dismissing the `UINavigationController`. (A back button is only visible if the device goes from compact-regular to regular-compact, in which case the `UISplitViewController` adds a back button to my presented `UINavigationController`.)

How do I handle this behavior to be as consistent as possible for dismissing this presented UINavigationController? Should I consider not using a UINavigationController for any particular reason? (and embed a ViewController only in certain cases instead?)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You would typically make the root view controller's `navigationItem` have a "done" button on the right, which dismisses the navigation controller

Comment: What about if the user wants to cancel or go back though? The back button is there in certain cases (on left side), and I don't want to remove that.

Comment: You typically can't cancel a modal navigation controller except from the root view. For example, in the Calendar app, create a new event and then tap "Repeat". A new VC is pushed onto the stack. You can't dismiss the navigation controller without tapping "Back" first, then "Cancel"

Comment: The weird part is that the default behaviour of my splitVC causes the newly presented VC to sometimes have a back button. Like if I have an iphone 6+ and use showViewcontroller(..), it has no button by default and appears to be presented modally, but then when I rotate to portrait, a back button appears in the top left. When I tap it, it is as if the ViewController was added to the UINavigationController stack. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISplitViewController/showViewController:sender:

Comment: @AaronBrager am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: That's how split view controller works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`